# Why do I get unpickling error for persistent sklearn model?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, persistence, pickle

I have a trained decision tree model which I created in a google research notebook, and pickled like this:

```
pickle.dump(tree, open(tree_15.sav, 'wb'))
```

We have an online analysis project built from docker, creating the same environment that I used to create the model. (And some other packages for other functionality.) I want to import my model in that other project, with the following line:

```
predictive_model = pickle.load(open(self.sav_path, 'rb'), fix_imports=True, encoding='latin1')
```

But I get:

```
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\xef'.
```

Funny thing is, I can not reproduce the same bug locally. I use a windows desktop (so I have problems with building from docker locally), but I use the same version of every package, the .sav file is not corrupted - hash checks out -, etc. It runs quite fine locally every time. The previous version of the same model ran online as well. I'm quite lost here to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

Often, `gzip`'s `open()` doesn't have the issues that the built-in `open()` has, so why not try the following:

```
import gzip, pickle
with gzip.open(self.sav_path, 'rb') as f:
    predictive_model = pickle.load(f, fix_imports=True, encoding='latin1')
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried your snippet, and now I get: OSError: Not a gzipped file (b'\x80\x03')